# How to save blocked site in Wayback Machine?

Tags: archive.org

Wayback Machine servers are present in U.S. I want to save an Uptobox site in Internet Archive Wayback Machine, but Uptobox is blocked in U.S., so in Wayback Machine it is also showing as blocked. How to save it? It's opening in my country.

Comment: You cannot. Wayback Machine can only save what it is possible for it to access.

Answer (score 1):

Contact ArchiveTeam, they handle things like this.

Comment: From [answer]: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better"

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. WayBack Machine can only save sites that it is able to access (if it cannot access them, it cannot get any data to save).

Comment: This is correct for the "save page now" button at the Internet Archive, but that's not the only way that we ingest web captures.